# How do you get a CSS inset box shadow on front?

Tags: css, foreground

I have a list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Citrus</li>
</ul>
```

When I put a background color on the `<li>` nodes the box-shadow (inset) that is on the `<ul>` node will be hidden. Is there a way I can get the inner shadow of the `<ul>` on the foreground so it will overlap the background-color of the `<li>` nodes?

ON REQUEST HERE IS THE SAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/JbAEL/
Hover with your mouse over the items and you will see the red background color will overlap the inner shadow removing the effect.

Comment: please set up an example using http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: you could mess with the `z-index` to change the layer order - but that could cause issues later (like if you're using links). Is the reason that you're not putting the background colour on the `<ul />` that the `<li />`s need to have different colours?

Comment: @Bogdan see link above. The z-index did not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML & CSS rely on a strict set of defined logic, and unfortunately do not have a way to order via `z-index` an element's content and it's background independently from each other and interweave them with different elements (as far as I'm aware).

Here's one proposed method, it's not the most ideal of solutions but sometimes breaking the rules involves getting dirty. Apply the shadow to each of your `li` elements and slide the shadow depending on which element it is on the list: top, bottom or any element in between.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><div>Elephant</div></li>
    <li><div>Monkey</div></li>
    <li><div>Snake</div></li>
    <li><div>Zebra</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li
{
    overflow:hidden; height:30px;
}

li div /* middle items (default) */
{
    box-shadow                : inset 0px 0px 10px #000000;
    -ms-box-shadow            : inset 0px 0px 10px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow            : inset 0px 0px 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow        : inset 0px 0px 10px #000000;
    line-height:30px; height:30px; margin-top:-30px; padding:30px 10px;
}

li:first-child div /* top item */
{
    margin-top:0; padding-top:0; padding-bottom:60px;
}

li:last-child div /* bottom item */
{
    margin-top:-60px; padding-top:60px; padding-bottom:0;
}
```

You can see the full code and demo at the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/JbAEL/2/), and seems to work fine in Firefox 11 and IE9, but can't vouch for other browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Talking about a dirty approach, since there is no `foreground` property ;) I decided to make the `UL` node relative, append it with a `div` node at absolute that carries the inner shadow.

For a working version:
http://jsfiddle.net/JbAEL/14/

Comment: I had to remove my upvote as if the ul is scrollable the shadow won't follow, see: http://jsfiddle.net/6vtra4ng/. Nice try though :)

Answer (score 1):

The `background-color` of your `li`s fall on top of the shadows. If you want to retain the shadow, you can make the background color slightly transparent. Try changing `background-color:red` to `background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.1)` say, where the last value is the opacity. This retains the inset box-shadow, but the color overlay will become a little faint.